# Needing help to modify existing batch file used to clear event viewers

Tags: file, batch-file, events, event-viewer

I have some code here that is being used to clear the event viewers on a few pcs. Currently I have to run this batch file with administrator access. Could someone help me in trying to modify it to just run normally.

Thanks

Comment: Here is the code @echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V    
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin   
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")   
echo.   
echo goto theEnd            
:do_clear    
echo clearing %1   
wevtutil.exe cl %1   
goto :eof   
:noAdmin  
exit

Comment: You need administrator rights to clear the event logs.

Comment: Ok. So at the minute i am just right clicking th batch and running as admin. Is there anything I could add to the code to run the batch file and throw up a prompt to enter admin password? Thanks

Comment: All in one line: `if /i not "%username%"=="administrator" ( runas /user:administrator "cmd.exe /c \"%~f0\"" & exit )`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
@echo off    
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V        
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin       
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%G")       
echo.   
echo goto theEnd            
:do_clear    
echo clearing %1   
wevtutil.exe cl %1   
goto :eof   
:noAdmin  
exit
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question is it? It's the code *for the question*. You should **edit** this into the question by using the small edit button under the question. Then delete this answer, otherwise no one will answer, thinking it's already been answered......